# Checking that inverses is included in a group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $A$ and $B$ be two normal subgroups of $G$.

I'm to check that $AB = \{ab\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

It's just this simple calculation I'm wondering about:

When checking if $(ab)^{-1} \in AB$. Is this allowed?

$b^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1} = a^{-1}b'\in AB$ for some $b' \in B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, but you need to explain:

- Since $A, B$ are groups, they are closed under inverses, so $a \in A \implies a^{-1} \in A$ and $b \in B \implies b^{-1} \in B$.
- Since $B$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $b^{-1} \in B$ and $a \in A \subseteq G$, we know that $ab^{-1}a^{-1} \in B$.
- Since $a^{-1} \in A$ and $ab^{-1}a^{-1} \in B$, it follows that $(a^{-1})(ab^{-1}a^{-1}) = (ab)^{-1} \in AB$.